# Checking in configuration files with sensitive information into code repos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, config

What is the best strategy in regards to checking in sensitive information into git? For example, database connection credentials, api keys, etc. For rails app, is it best to add environment files to .gitignore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use environment variables.

Check out these two links. The second link will show you how to keep your sensitive information secure by using environment variables to store sensitive data.

[Rails Environment Variables](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)

[Environment Variables in Ruby on Rails](http://richonrails.com/articles/environment-variables-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you don't need to ignore your env files - just remove all the secrets and use config variables ibstead... you can then refer to them using `ENV['varname']`

This gist shows one way of doing that using SECRET_KEY_BASE as an example (but you should do it with every sensitive key you have):
https://gist.github.com/cjolly/6265302